# how to insert info into online excel spreadsheet with python selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, selenium

Is it possible, to insert information into excel spreadsheet with selenium? for example I want have several rows and categories, and be able to insert specific info to specific category. this is how my spreadsheet looks like.
[image]

also are there any alternatives?

Comment: You can use ```openpyxl```.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found one of the ways I could use and maybe others can find it useful. for the purpose of inserting data I can use seleniums ActionChains

```
driver.get(https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/.........)
actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.send_keys(Keys.DOWN + 't')
actions.perform()
```

In this case for example, when driver opens the webpage and you click the down arrow button, tab moves to first column second row and then inserts "t". Its possible to write a function where you specify coordinates, For example which row and which column u need to go to, to insert the data, meaning how many times do you need to click left right up and down. This solves my problem, but i would like to hear better solutions.